# PHP allowed memory usage exhausted while I see no sign of it

Tags: php

I have this simple PHP script that contains only the following few lines

```
$mem = memory_get_usage()/1024;
$mem = $mem/1024;
echo "mem: ".$mem ."Mb<br>";
$max =  ini_get('memory_limit');
echo "max is $max<br>";

$filename = 'upload/orig/CID_553.jpg';              
$filesize = (filesize($filename) / 1024);
echo "filesize is $filesize Kb<br>";        
$img_pointer = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
```

When running it, I get this output

```
mem: 0.30711364746094Mb
max is 64M
filesize is 952.2666015625 Kb
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13056 bytes) in C:\temp_checkmem.php on line 13
```

How is it possible that loading a file of 952Kb will trap PHP (imagecreatefrompeg) into going over the allowed 64Mb of memory ? Any ideas?

Comment: make sure you're using `imagedestroy($img_pointer)` at last

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because the JPG file is only 952kbytes doesn't mean it can't occupy a **VERY** large amount of memory, e.g.a simple test with a 2048x2048 pure white image produces a 59kbyte .jpg file.

That file will decompress to a `2048x2048x3 = 12.6` megabyte raw bitmap in GD.

You can get a rough estimate of how much memory WOULD be required by GD to load/decompress the image with:

```
$stats = getimagesize($filename);
$memory_estimate = $stats[0] * $stats[1] * 3; // height * width * 3 bytes per pixel
echo "{$stats[0]}x{$stats[1]} -> {$memory_estimate} bytes";
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible, that the raw picture or internal format of the picture gets over the memory limit.

Try to load a big picture and save it as bitmap, it's huge..

Every pixel takes 3 byte (24 bit color mode), `0-255 red` `0-255 green`, `0-255 blue`.

On opening the file with an additional alpha channel `imagealphablending();`, you have 4 byte per pixel (32 bit color mode), making an additional `0-255 for alpha blending`.

```
2,5 MB JPG (100% quality) ~ 36,0 MB bitmap - 12 megapixel    
4,1 MB JPG (100% quality) ~ 96,0 MB bitmap - 32 megapixel
```

compare with this tool:

http://web.forret.com/tools/megapixel.asp

see wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Color#True_color_.2824-bit.29